# angular directives: add DOM elements with ng functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive for a small input field that only takes text and dynamically changes a symbol from searchglass to X, if there is text inside and erases this text when it is clicked.
Therefore I add the neccesary HTML to the input but just can get the native ng directive running. I'm quite new to angular and hope, someone can help. There are some similar questions out there, but none really helps.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('searchBox', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            }
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var appendix = angular.element(
                    '<span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="ngModel = none">' +
                    '  <i ng-hide="ng-model" class="fa fa-search"></i>' +
                    '  <i ng-show="ng-model" class="fa fa-close"></i>' +
                    '</span>');
                var wrapper = angular.element(
                    '<div class="input-group input-group-sm search-box-custom"></div>'
                );
                element
                    .wrap(wrapper)
                    .after(appendix);

                element.removeAttr("search-box"); //prevent endless compile loop
                element.removeAttr("data-search-box"); //prevent endless compile loop*/
                $compile(appendix)(scope);

            }
        };
    });
```

ng-model is defined in the input field

```
<input search-box
       type="text"
       ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}"
       ng-model="inputValue"
       placeholder="Hier Tippen..." />
```

edit: the directive should have an own scope that is connected to the parent scope, but should not be the same because parent value may differ in other situations

Comment: Please share your HTML where the directive is used. More over, it would be better you to provide a jsFiddle or plunker.

Comment: added the input. 'inputValue' itself has it's representation in the corresponding controller and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code, it should work properly.

```
var appendix = angular.element(
   '<span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="inputValue = null">' +
   '  <i ng-hide="inputValue" class="fa fa-search"></i>' +
   '  <i ng-show="inputValue" class="fa fa-close"></i>' +
   '</span>');
```

More over, I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnMhx/192/), please look at.

**Useful information:**

The `scope` property can be true, an object or a falsy value:

1. `falsy`: No scope will be created for the directive. The directive will use its parent's scope.
2. `true`: A new child scope that prototypically inherits from its parent will be created for the directive's element. If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new scope.
3. `{...}` (an object hash): A new "isolate" scope is created for the directive's element. The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope. This is useful when creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope.

By default, no scope is created. That's the case you've got in your directive, which means you can access `inputValue` directly from your custom directive.

**Edit 1**

Look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnMhx/193/) for details. The main concept is to use `modelSetter` and `modelGetter` together with helpfull functions:

```
let modelGetter = $parse(attrs['ngModel']);
let modelSetter = modelGetter.assign;

scope.reset = function () {
    modelSetter(scope, null);
};

scope.isEmpty = function () {
    return !modelGetter(scope);
};

var appendix = angular.element(
    '<span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="reset()">' +
    '  <i ng-show="isEmpty()" class="fa fa-search">Search</i>' +
    '  <i ng-hide="isEmpty()" class="fa fa-close">Delete</i>' +
    '</span>');
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thx for your answer.
actually, I dont want to directly access the parent scope within the directive to keep it dynamic. So I tried to add
`scope {
ngModel: '=',
}`
to the directive, but then it won't work any more.

Comment: @Phloppy Please look at the **Edit 1**. One more note: an isolated scope shouldn't be added to the directive taking into account the way it's applied and working. That's the reason why it didn't work in the case you mentioned above in your comment.

Comment: ah, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. I'll have closer look on the functionality of $parse to fully understand it.
One last question concerning this topic, thats not quite clear to me:
I've read a lot, that DOM manipulations should only be done in the 'compile' part of the directive and not the 'link' part. 
But isn't this 'wrap' and 'after' exactly manipulating the DOM? Just to be sure to have clean angular code in the end :)

Comment: @Phloppy Read the following two articles from the Angular JS documentation. It should help you. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements